# Mysql error when trying to get distance from long and lat

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

basically I have a database that is setup in Longitude and Latitude. I have been trying for hours now to fix an issue I have with MySql and I can not find my error. Here is the error I am getting:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '€“ longitude) * PI() / 180))* 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)*1.609344) AS distance' at line 1

Here is MySql database query to get the distances from long and lat:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT *, (((ACOS(SIN(".$latitude." * PI() / 180) * SIN(latitude *
 PI() / 180) + COS(".$latitude." * PI() / 180) * COS(latitude * PI() / 180) * 
COS((".$longitude." – longitude) * PI() / 180))* 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515)*1.609344) 
AS distance") or die(mysql_error());
```

Please please please help!!!

Comment: Print out $res (after the substitutions) and look at that portion of the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minus-sign looking character at which the error occurs doesn't appear to be a minus-sign. Perhaps you used Word (or a similar "helpful" editor) to construct the query, and it substituted a "smart" version of a minus-sign, like an en-dash?

I replaced that character with a proper minus sign and the query worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are doing `SELECT *,` and you have no `FROM` clause specified.
Remove the `*,` from the query or add the `FROM` and the table you fetch the data from.

Comment: COS((".$longitude." – longitude) * PI()

Comment: I am trying to subtract my var $longitude from longitud in the table..... I dont see how this is a string.

Comment: Where do you specify the table?